# create plot in ggplot for each unique value in a row in r

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, iteration, purrr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Janet", "Marisa"),
                  x = c(100, 50, 75),
                  y = c(2, 3, 6))
```

Each name is unique, and I want to make a bar graph for each person without having to do it line by line. I also want to save each plot as a unique object because I'll be inputting it into a power point using the officer package. Last, the names won't always be the same, but each name *will* always be unique.

For instance, I want one plot for Janet, one plot for Justin, and one plot for Marisa. I don't want them faceted but instead as their own objects.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the data in long format first and for each individual `name` create the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
long_data <- my_data %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = 'col')

plots_list <- map(unique(my_data$name), ~long_data %>%
                   filter(name == .x) %>%
                   ggplot() + aes(name, value, fill = col) + 
                   geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') + 
                   scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'blue')) + 
                   ggtitle(paste0('Plot for ', .x)))
```

This will return list of plots where individual plots can be accessed via `plots_list[[1]]`, `plots_list[[2]]` etc.

```
plots_list[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I should have been clearer--I want 3 plots. One for Janet, one for just, one for marisa

Comment: So same individual bar graphs for each? Or do you want to have facets?

Comment: not facets--the same bar graph for each individual, ideally each as their own object